# javascript - adding properties to array objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, properties

I'm trying to loop through a pipe delimited list passed to a function, split it out into an array based on the pipe as a separator, and then break each item out into its component parts, where the format is as follows:

"76:1167|76:1168"

so that the array would be: surveyQuestions[0] = 76:1167. And then that would be split up into : surveyQuestions[0].question = 76 and surveyQuestions[0].answer = 1167.

And this is the code I'm using, but the values come back undefined when I try to add the properties to each array item.

```
function answerSurvey(survey){

var surveyResults = survey.split("|");

for (var i=0;i<surveyResults.length;i++){

    var surveyResult = surveyResults[i].split(":");
    var surveyQ = surveyResult[0];
    var surveyA = surveyResult[1];
    surveyResults[i].surveyQ = surveyQ;
    surveyResults[i].surveyA = surveyA;
    console.log(surveyResults[i].surveyQ + "|" + surveyResults[i].surveyA)
}

}

answerSurvey("76:1167|76:1168");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to add a property to a string, which you cannot do.  If you want the Array to contain a list of Objects, use `Array.map()` to transform your strings into objects:

```
var surveyResults = survey.split("|").map(function (result) {
    var parts = result.split(":");
    return {
        question: parts[0],
        answer: parts[1]
    };
});
```

It is included in most browsers, but for older versions of some browsers, you'll need to [add `.map()` manually](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatibility).

**Edit:** jQuery does add a map function (as noted in the comments).  Tweak the code above slightly to include the array as the first parameter to `$.map()` and substitute the argument name for `this` (or shift the `result` argument one to the right, following `index`):

```
var surveyResults = $.map(survey.split("|"), function (i, result) {
    var parts = result.split(":");  // or this.split(":")
    return {
        question: parts[0],
        answer: parts[1]
    };
});
```

Comment: Also, the asker seems to be using jQuery, which offers a cross-browser implementation: `$.map(array,function)`

Comment: Thanks Jens - I'll probably do that

Comment: Good observation!  I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function answerSurvey(survey){

var surveyResults = survey.split("|");

for (var i=0;i<surveyResults.length;i++){

    var surveyResult = surveyResults[i].split(":");
    var surveyQ = surveyResult[0];
    var surveyA = surveyResult[1];
    surveyResults[i] = {};
    surveyResults[i].surveyQ = surveyQ;
    surveyResults[i].surveyA = surveyA;
    console.log(surveyResults[i].surveyQ + "|" + surveyResults[i].surveyA)
}

}

answerSurvey('76:1167|76:1168');
```

Comment: Corret. To point out the only difference to the OP, it's declaring surveyResults[i] to be an object ({}). Also, the argument for answerSurvey needs quotes around it.

Answer (score 0):

`surveyResults[i]` is a 'string' not an object, so you can't add properties to it.

Try this:

```
var surveyQ = surveyResult[0];
var surveyA = surveyResult[1];
surveyResults[i] = {};
surveyResults[i].surveyQ = surveyQ;
surveyResults[i].surveyA = surveyA;
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/WeJxe/